Keep waiting in Kotlin for other jobs/children to finish, if one fails
I have pusub subscriber in the server, which runs parallel tasks and needs to wait for all of them to finish.
Currently when one child throws an exception, it corrupts completely the whole subscriber, and the whole pipeline is broken.
Then, I tried adding a try-catch for the CancellationException of the "problematic" child.
However, then I noticed that is does not make the subscriber wait for all of the tasks, despite the fact that they do continue to process.
       try {
            listOf(
                async {
                    // A - fails
                    delay(timeMillis(seconds = 0.5))
                    throw CancellationException()
                },
                async {
                    delay(timeMillis(seconds = 10))
                    println("B finished")
                },
                async {
                    delay(timeMillis(seconds = 5))
                    println("C finished")
                }
            ).awaitAll()
        } catch (e: CancellationException) {
            println("cancellation!")
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            println("throwable!")
        }
        println("All finished -----------------")

What I see printed is :
cancellation!
All finished -----------------
C finished
B finished

But I need to be able to wait until B and C are finished, even if A fails/throws exception.
In other words I want this behavior :
cancellation! (A fails)
C finished
B finished
All finished -----------------

How can that be achieved?

What do you need to do with the result of the operation that failed? I mean, you used async instead of launch, which suggests you wait for some data, then you do awaitAll which again suggests results are important to you. But you don't return anything from tasks and you entirely ignore the return value of awaitAll. So do you need results or only make sure jobs executed? Also, why the failed tasks throws CancellationException? This is not a typical way to signal failures. CancellationException has a very special meaning, it doesn't represent a failure.

I actually don't need the result. Things like updating statuses in DB for example are done inside the tasks. So I only need to make sure the jobs are executed, otherwise the aforementioned status updates in DB are not done, and tasks are just stuck pending simply because one of the jobs had some internal exception/error

and regarding the cancellation exception, it was just something I noticed was thrown in the logs, so I tried to imitate it

To wait for a group of coroutines to all finish, regardless of failure, and without needing to return results, use supervisorScope and launch for each of them. You can use a CoroutineExceptionHandler for logging the errors.
Don't throw CancellationExceptions to represent your own failures. This can mess up the way coroutines work. CancellationException is a special tool coroutines use to make prompt cancellation of coroutines work.
Don't catch CancellationExceptions without rethrowing them.
So corrected code looks like:
supervisorScope {
    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e -> 
        println("throwable! $e") 
    }
    launch(handler) {
        // A - fails
        delay(timeMillis(seconds = 0.5))
        throw Exception("a failed")
    }
    launch(handler) {
        delay(timeMillis(seconds = 10))
        println("B finished")
    }
    launch(handler) {
        delay(timeMillis(seconds = 5))
        println("C finished")
    }
}


async should be launch. It will work regardless, but async implies that we are interested in the return value (which we are not).

Yes, that’s what I meant to put! Thank you.

Thank you! So I understand the "internals" more - do you happen to know what is the rationale by Kotlin to propagate even properly caught&handled exceptions to the whole parent scope?  So that we need the supervisor

I'm not sure what you mean. They won't propagate if caught at the source. In your example, you deferred catching until after the coroutines have already completed, so one of those coroutines is failed, not "properly caught and handled". If you are asking why that causes its siblings to fail if there is no supervisor scope, I think it's natural to think that in the majority of cases, a failure of any part is a failure of the whole task. It's less common to fire off tasks where it doesn't matter if a portion of the subtasks fail.

I think simulating a failure by throwing the CancellationException is not a good idea, because this is a very special exception which doesn't signal a failure, but a cancellation. The answer could be a little different if we assume this is the only exception that may happen, but I assume we need a solution that works for actual failures, so any exception.
The standard way to ignore failures and let sibling tasks run without interruptions is by using the supervisorScope or SupervisorJob:
suspend fun main() {
    supervisorScope {
        launch {
            delay(0.5.seconds)
            throw Exception()
        }
        launch {
            delay(10.seconds)
            println("B finished")
        }
        launch {
            delay(5.seconds)
            println("C finished")
        }
    }
}

If we need more control over the exception handling, we need to log it, etc., we can catch the exception, but we should do this inside the launch block, not outside it. Note however, that if the child coroutine is in the failed state already, then simply catching the exception won't stop it from propagating to the parent coroutine. In this case we still have to use the supervisorScope.

thank you. Regarding your last sentence, why does properly catching an exception still causes "chaos" in parent scopes or other "children"?
What is Kotlin's rationale behind this?

The last sentence describes the case where you the child coroutine has already failed before you've attempted to catch its exception outside that child coroutine. In this case, the default behavior (without supervisor) is to propagate the failure. I suppose they could invert the behavior and have a "successRequiredScope" needed for this propagating behavior, but they chose the more common need as default. Most commonly, if part of your task has failed, you cannot trust the end result, so the whole task is a failure.
